# Application that arrange files in the whole computer

Tags: windows, file-management

Do you know of any application that works like this:

1. Allows you to create folders where the files in number 2 will be placed.
2. Allows you arrange all/any of the files in the computer according to file type, date, size, etc.

Comment: platform is some version of windows, i presume?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is also [Belvedere](http://lifehacker.com/341950/belvedere-automates-your-self+cleaning-pc) which is from one of my favorite tech and productivity sites [lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com) Its definitely worth a look. Also if your not to afraid of learning a little [auto hot key](http://www.autohotkey.com/) scripting you could write one yourself without too much trouble.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/)?

Comment: Yah, I wasn't exactly sure what you were looking for.  I use Total Commander for much of my file handling instead of Windows Explorer...  Good luck with your project!